# How to Design Searching Users and Friends using ElasticSearch?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

In our app, we have users and users can have friends (think Facebook, relationship is bi-directional). We would like to be able to:

1. Have a site-wide search for users by name or username
2. Allow each user to search her friends by name or username

What would be the best approach to design this keeping in mind that:

1. A user can have up to 50k friends.
2. Users can change their names and usernames all the time

Answer (score 2):

I am going to suggest another technology which I think will help you with this problem. You can check [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) (graph database) which will help you to make relations (user-friend) and traverse graph easily.

You can also use Lucene as an seperate Index engine with Neo4j and make full-text search. [Check here.](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/indexing.html)

Also, you can find an examples below which could be helpful.

- [Lucene Integration with Neo4j](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/07/homegrown-lucene-integration-with-neo4j.html)
- [Lucene Full Text Indexing with Neo4j](http://romikoderbynew.com/2011/08/28/lucene-full-text-indexing-with-neo4j/)

PS : I have no relationship with Neo4j.

Comment: Can this combination do searches like "guys named like Mark among my friends"?

Answer (score 1):

Have documents like:

```
type:friendship
parties_name:[mark zuckerburg, bill gates]
parties_id:[1, 753634] (what if many people are named bill gates)
```

So there will be one such row for each friendship in your network, and when our particular `mark zuckerburg` updates his friendships (and name), all rows `parties_id:1` must be reindexed.

Comment: I was really wishing I could avoid that, but I guess there is no way around it.

Comment: could you post a example of the XML's schema? Thanks

Comment: Well, `type` as string, `parties_name` as n-grammed/stemmed text and `parties_id` as int are good choices.